# How do I restore a backup from Duplicity?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

Totally new to using Linux, I've got a backup which was made using deja-dup last week and the backup appears to be in 2 folders which are stored on a external HDD under these locations:

```
SAMSUNG/backup
SAMSUNG/Ubuntu Backup
```

The backups are split into volumes:

[image: multiple archives in folder]

[image: multiple archives in folder]

I've created a separate partition to restore the files too labelled "Backup" with the drive letter R.

I need to know how to restore the backups, I've been looking around and I am confused on how to go about it.